# Field-level setting in the Campaign object

Tags: fls

- In my project, I create the Campaign object through Site.
- On public site setting, I configured (FLS)field level setting for all Custom fields in the Campaign Object.
- Access the site above to create new Campaign Object.

**Expected**: Campaign will be inserted in table Campaign.
**Actual**: Campaign insert fail.

When run debug, I saw this problem occur when I check FLS(in my source code).
All custom fields is not creatable although they was set before.

I cannot understand.
Please help me clear this case.
P/S: I think my problem is similar this topic
[Schema sObjectType [Object] fields isUpdateable returns false despite profile config](http://Schema%20sObjectType%20[Object]%20fields%20isUpdateable%20returns%20false%20despite%20profile%20config)
I checked on the "Marketing User". But occur the error:
"Marketing User is not allowed for this License Type."

How can I do to resolve it??

Comment: Have you also checked "Marketing User" on the site user record?

Comment: Thanks Girbot. Because the lience of them is Guest. So I can not check "Marketing User".... Can I do something to pass this case??

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can set a Guest Site User to be a Marketing user, you just need to get to the User page not the profile page.

I did this using the below,

```
select Id, username from user where name like '%guest%'
```

Getting the Id then populating the url:
https//[your instance].salesforce.com/userId

But you could probably find a record created via the user and click through the lookup.

The screenshot below is from the edit page of site user:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Girbot! I try to do as you say. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do as you say. But nothing changed. Did you save the user with "Marketing User" successful??
[image]